# What happens to the material from meteors that "burn up" in the atmosphere?

Tags: meteors

Although people speak of meteors "burning up" in the atmosphere, we know that they actually ablate.  I'm not sure whether, during ablation, the material that comes off of the (heated) meteor is initially liquid or gas, but, whichever it is, how does it end up after it cools?  Does the ablated material end up as solid particles in the atmosphere?

Comment: "Although people speak of meteors "burning up" in the atmosphere, we know that they actually ablate." Could you please explain? I understand that some meteors ablate, but some meteors contain iron and other metals and oxidize (and in my book, that means "burn") in flight. See, e.g., https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/maps.12645 : "I-type cosmic spherules consist largely of wustite (FeO) and magnetite (Fe3O4) but may retain a bead of remnant metal (e.g., Genge et al. 2008). Significant oxidation thus occurs during atmospheric flight."

Comment: I would agree that if iron is oxidized, that is burning.  The question was more about what happens to the material after it is no longer part of the original meteor.  Mike answered that it becomes meteoric dust.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [Meteoric dust](https://earthsky.org/space/tons-of-extraterrestrial-dust-fall-to-earth-each-year/) is landing on the earth all the time.